# prefix to infix in php

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I'm trying to implement prefix to infix in PHP. The input should be for example something like this:

```
prefix  * + 3 2 4
infix   ((3+2)*4)
```

I want to convert prefix expression like `(* + 3 2 4)` into infix expression using PHP or JavaScript `(((3+2)*4))`.

Comment: Please ask a question ;) And add your code if you want to know more.

Comment: I want to convert prefix expression like (* + 3 2 4) into infix expression using php or javascript (((3+2)*4))

Comment: "that's what i've got so far"... what's what you've got so far?

Comment: can you give one more example ....

Comment: Come on, even the first google result gives you the algorithms to use for it. :|

Comment: i think the question is "How to convert prefix expression like (* + 3 2 4) into infix expression using php or javascript (((3+2)*4))" 

and please don't down vote i known its doesn't met the quality requirement but i am talking about the caring of beginner i hopes now no one down vote

Comment: yes. i want the same thing.If you have any idea that how can achieve this? any example code in php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exemplary object oriented AST and parser:

```
$prefix = '* + 3 2 4';
$parser = new InfixPrefixParser($prefix);
$node = $parser->parse();
echo $node, "\n"; # ((3 + 2) * 4)
echo ' = ', $node->evaluate(), "\n"; # 20
```

The parser:

```
class InfixPrefixParser extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function __construct($prefix)
    {
        $tokens = new ArrayIterator(preg_split('/\s/', $prefix, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
        parent::__construct($tokens);
    }

    /**
     * @return InfixNode
     */
    public function current()
    {
        $string = parent::current();
        parent::next();
        $operators = array('*' => 'Mult', '+' => 'Plus');
        $class = 'InfixNode' . (isset($operators[$string]) ? 'Operator' . $operators[$string] : 'Value');
        $node = new $class($string);
        if ($node instanceof InfixNodeOperator) {
            $node->setLeft($this->current());
            $node->setRight($this->current());
        }
        return $node;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->parse();
    }

    public function parse()
    {
        $this->rewind();
        return $this->current();
    }
}
```

The object model for the AST

```
abstract class InfixNode
{
    abstract function evaluate();
}

abstract class InfixNodeOperator extends InfixNode
{
    private $operator;
    protected $left;
    protected $right;

    public function __construct($operator)
    {
        $this->operator = $operator;
    }

    public function setLeft(InfixNode $node)
    {
        $this->left = $node;
    }

    public function getLeft()
    {
        return $this->left;
    }

    public function setRight(InfixNode $node)
    {
        $this->right = $node;
    }

    public function getRight()
    {
        return $this->right;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf('(%s %s %s)', $this->left, $this->operator, $this->right);
    }
}

class InfixNodeOperatorMult extends InfixNodeOperator
{
    public function evaluate()
    {
        return $this->left->evaluate() * $this->right->evaluate();
    }
}

class InfixNodeOperatorPlus extends InfixNodeOperator
{
    public function evaluate()
    {
        return $this->left->evaluate() + $this->right->evaluate();
    }
}

class InfixNodeValue extends InfixNode
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->value;
    }

    public function evaluate()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

I'm not very confident with the wording, because the nodes aren't exactly fully related to infix, large parts of them could be used for prefix or postfix as well, only the `__toString()` functions are infix related actually.

---

(old version) Some PHP code, using some recursive parse function and an object model for the nodes. Usage:

```
$prefix = '* + 3 2 4';

$tokens = new ArrayIterator(preg_split('/\s/', $prefix, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

$parse = function() use ($tokens, &$parse) {
    $string = $tokens->current(); $tokens->next();
    $isOperator = in_array($string, array('*', '+'));
    $class = 'InfixNode' . ($isOperator ? 'Operator' : 'Value');
    $node = new $class($string);
    if ($node instanceof InfixNodeOperator) {
        $node->setLeft($parse());
        $node->setRight($parse());
    }
    return $node;
};

echo $parse(); # ((3 + 2) * 4)
```

The node classes:

```
class InfixNode {}

class InfixNodeOperator extends InfixNode
{
    private $operator;
    private $left;
    private $right;
    public function __construct($operator) {
        $this->operator = $operator;
    }
    public function setLeft(InfixNode $node) {
        $this->left = $node;
    }
    public function getLeft() {
        return $this->left;
    }
    public function setRight(InfixNode $node) {
        $this->right = $node;
    }
    public function getRight() {
        return $this->right;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return sprintf('(%s %s %s)', $this->left, $this->operator, $this->right);
    }
}

class InfixNodeValue extends InfixNode
{
    private $value;
    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1178695: You're welcome, I extended the answer again so it can actually evaluate and the parser is more encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

This the basic algorithm for **Prefix** to **Postfix** notation (using a `stack`):

```
   IF stack is not empty
     a. Temp -->pop the stack
     b. IF temp is a operator
       i. Write a opening parenthesis to output
       ii. prefixToInfix(stack)
       iii. Write temp to output
       iv. prefixToInfix(stack)
       v. Write a closing parenthesis to output
    c. ELSE IF temp is a space -->prefixToInfix(stack)
    d. ELSE
       i. Write temp to output
       ii. IF stack.top NOT EQUAL to space -->prefixToInfix(stack)
```

Try studying it a bit, and testing it (with the great pencil-and-paper method).

Comment: Thanks for answer and please also vote up the question to keep the balance thanks